# Machine learning model that takes multiple records as input to help predict the last

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm, machine-learning-model, linear-regression

I want to create a ML model that is able to forecast the yield from a farm. My data source gives me data about the inspections from the field, but that is too much info to fit in 1 record, so there are like 10 records with all different inspection data with the predicted yield (which is the same for all records because they are from the same day) and then I have the initial estimated yield with the start record, and then the final yield from the last day when the crops are harvested.

Now the problem I see arising is that when I train a model on this, I ofcourse can only give 1 record as an input. So I want to know if there is a model that lets you give 10 inputs first, which are making a difference for the final outcome (so that my field inspection data will have influence on the final yield record, while its not in the same record)

Is this possible at all?

Yield estimates (start date, some point in the middle, and the final date so the real yield):

```
SELECT
    ProductionFields.FieldNumber AS ID,
    ProductionFields.City AS City,
    ProductionContracts.ProductionArea AS Region,
    Products.Crop AS Crop,
    ProductionContracts.Date AS EventDate,
    'YIELD-ESTIMATE' AS EventType,
    ProductionFields.ReceivedQuantity AS EventValue,
    ProductionFields.ReceivedQuantity AS EstimatedQuantity
FROM ...
```

Inspection data:

```
SELECT
    ProductionFields.FieldNumber AS ID,
    ProductionFields.City AS City,
    ProductionContracts.ProductionArea AS Region,
    Products.Crop AS Crop,
    ProductionFieldInspections.InspectionDate AS EventDate,
    ProductionFieldInspections.Code AS EventType,
    ProductionFieldInspections.Value AS EventValue,
    ProductionFieldInspections.EstimatedQuantity AS EstimatedQuantity
FROM ...
```

So this gives me these kind of results:

Record 1: Yield estimate on start day

Records 2-10: Different kind of inspection info (plant quality, soil quality....) with a yield estimate

Record 11: Some random yield estimate at the end of the season

Record 12: Final yield when the crops are harvested

This is all for the same field with the same crop:
[image: Database]